# Constraint on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, constraints, alter

I have a table that contains 7 columns(f_name, l_name, sex, birth_date, matri_num,dept,sal) and i want to add a constraint to verify that of out the 3 columns(f_name, l_name,birth_date) at least 2 was filled.

Comment: what have you tried?  Also, Why? Having a first name and birthdate doesn't seem that useful?

Comment: it's a test i am doing for something bigger. i need such a constraint. And i know it is the check constraint to be such but i don't know if it is possible to such 'and' or 'or' in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table>
  ADD CONSTRAINT TWO_FILLED
  CHECK(NVL2(F_NAME, 1, 0) + NVL2(L_NAME, 1, 0) + NVL2(BIRTH_DATE, 1, 0) >= 2);
```